# Problema ao incluir chave estrangeira no Mysql

Tags: mysql

Alguém pode me ajudar? ao tentar adicionar a foreign key, é apresentada a seguinte mensagem: "Error code 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint".

```
/*create table Processo*/

create table Processo(
Numero_processo varchar(15) not null,
Acao varchar(40),
Vara varchar(30),
Servidor_expeditor varchar(30),
Matricula varchar(10) unique,
Email varchar(40),
Primary Key (Numero_processo)
);


/*criando tabela Cartorio*/

create table Cartorio(

Matricula varchar(10) not null unique,
Servidor_solicitante varchar(30) not null,
Secao varchar(30),
Telefone varchar(15),
Email varchar(40),
Ocupacao varchar(30),
Fk_Numero_processo int,
primary key (Matricula),
foreign key (Fk_Numero_processo) references processo (Numero_processo)
);
```

Comment: Numero_processo x numero_processo , em Banco de Dadis faça tudo em "uppercase".

Comment: Mesmo assim continua dando erro...

Comment: Edita a pergunta com o novo script.

Answer (score -2):

A chave primaria e a estrangeira têm de ser do mesmo tipo (na tabela "processo" está varchar e a estrangeira como int). Alias, recomendo que faça o contrário: o campo chave primaria de cartorio deve ser chave estrangeira da tabela processo.
Se for usar "Matricula" tire o "unique".
Outra obs: sua tabela processo não tem autor, réu, tipo de ação, nome dos advogados... até + e boa sorte. :-)

Answer (score -3):

No seu caso, a tabela Processo tem a coluna Numero_processo como chave primária, mas na tabela Cartorio, a chave estrangeira Fk_Numero_processo é do tipo int, enquanto Numero_processo na tabela Processo é do tipo varchar(15).

Além disso, a declaração de Fk_Numero_processo precisa estar no mesmo tipo de dados da coluna referenciada. Portanto, você deve corrigir a tabela Cartorio para resolver esses problemas. Aqui está a versão corrigida, considerando que o Numero_processo será um campo que poderá armazenar caracteres alterei para ficar como varchar em ambas tabelas. Caso seja somente numeros deve ser alterado para int.

```
/*create table Processo*/

create table Processo(
    Numero_processo varchar(15) not null,
    Acao varchar(40),
    Vara varchar(30),
    Servidor_expeditor varchar(30),
    Matricula varchar(10) unique,
    Email varchar(40),
    Primary Key (Numero_processo)
);

/*criando tabela Cartorio*/

create table Cartorio(
    Matricula varchar(10) not null unique,
    Servidor_solicitante varchar(30) not null,
    Secao varchar(30),
    Telefone varchar(15),
    Email varchar(40),
    Ocupacao varchar(30),
    Fk_Numero_processo varchar(15), -- Alterado para varchar(15)
    primary key (Matricula),
    foreign key (Fk_Numero_processo) references Processo (Numero_processo)
);
```